# Primary key error logging in Django Admin using MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-admin

first of all, I'm new in MongoDB and this is my first application using it so I know I have lack of documentation reading, but I am trying to find solution to this problem due that the documentation read says that everything might work well with no changes.

I have correctly configured the settings file with the MongoDB database and have created my models.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}
```

I have created a superuser using the `django-admin createsuperuser` but when I try to login into the admin panel I get this error.

```
ValueError: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
```

I know that MongoDB doesn't have a Primary Key and Foreign Key system and it's based on JSON-like type objects, but the documentation say that it works well with it so I thought that it was previously ready to run this.

Any clue of what is happening?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error show that `id(primsry_key)` is not created by Django

Causes:

1. `makemigrations` your Django project for SQL databases (mysql, sqlite, etc.) or Mongo Cloud database in the past, and then just migrate your project without `makemigrations`.
2. Create an `auth_user` collection (collections in MongoDB are almost like tables in a  SQL database) or try `createsuperuser` in the past, and then try `makemigrations` and migrate your project.

Solution:

1. Connect to your database with MongoDB with MongoDB Compass
2. Drop your `project` database
3. `makemigrations` and migrate your Django project again
4. `createsuperuser`

Finally, check that `id(django primary_key)` and `_id(mongodb objectId)` is available in `auth_user` and other collections.

[image: a object in auth_user collection(mongodb compass)]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've updated your answer to help improve the formatting. Instead of using a screenshot of data, prefer including that data as text, and using Markdown to format it as code. Can you make that modification?

Answer (score 0):

I did what Jeremy answered and it solve my problem, but I did have to add an id manually.